# How do I find my contacts?

Tags: contacts

My contacts have dissapeared from my phone, over night, for no reason. (Galaxy S) Althoug nothing else in the phone has been affected. The messages still exist, the history is there, but only listed with phone numbers and not my contacts. I have pulled the battery, I have pulled the sim card and battery together and I have restarted the phone. Nothing seems to work. I beleive the contacts are in the phone because under my history some names appear but not all of them. How do I trace /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db  to see if my contacts exist at all. Where do I start?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you just unchecked some/all contact sources from showing up in the contact list?

Open the contact list -> open the context menu -> hit 'more' -> choose view settings

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your contacts have been swallowed by your google account and are no longer phone-only contacts. If that is the case you can get your contacts back in the "Display Options" inside your contacts/phone app. Just choose to display google contacts and see if they're there.

And, to open a .db file (an sqlite database) you need the proper software ([maybe a market app?](https://market.android.com/search?q=sqlite&c=apps)), some of them are free and easy to use, but I warn you, contacts.db is ugly as hell.